# Use VS Code extension variable in task.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

How I can define a variable with extension scope, and the same can be used in task.json.

It's like I can set the value of SelectedAppId variable and the variable I can use in task.json

```
        {
            "name": "Debug (Development)",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/$(<Config>.<ExtensionName>.<VarialbeName>)",
        }
```

Comment: do you want to be able to use a setting as the result of a variable in task.json? Can you give an example of the settings you like to use? Where is this `SelectedAppId` defined? Please give a full example of what you want to configure in which files.

Answer (score 3):

VS Code doesn't provide a way to make arbitrary `${}` style variables for tasks.json and launch.json, but your extension can define a setting and reference it as `${config:myExtensionsNewSetting}`: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_configuration-variables
Alternatively, you can use an environment variable: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a Command in your extension and register it with a name, e.g. "my_extension_id.variable_name".
Now you can access the command with this syntax: `${command:my_extension_id.variable_name}`
For details please see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables